# manual FB login integration ( without SDK)

Tags: facebook, web

FB dialog gives me no feedback so that I can parse token from url and close it. Window event is stuck in onunload event.

The below code builds my FB url which I then open in Window.open function. But my token is never resolved or rejected because load is never fired.

```
  buildUrlFb = () => {
    let params = "fbloged=1";
    return `https://www.facebook.com/v13.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=${FB_ID}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&state=${params}`;
  };

  
popupWindow = (url, windowName, win, w, h) => {
    const y = win.top.outerHeight / 2 + win.top.screenY - h / 2;
    const x = win.top.outerWidth / 2 + win.top.screenX - w / 2;
    return win.open(
      url,
      windowName,
      `toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=${w}, height=${h}, top=${y}, left=${x}`
    );
  };


  openFbDialog = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let uri = this.buildUrlFb();
      let window01 = this.popupWindow(uri, "Sign in with Fb", window, 500, 500);


      window01.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
        try {
          let uri02 = window01.location.href;
          let token = this.getUrlParameter("code", uri02); //  when the server will be handling the token
          // console.log("pop up token", token);
          resolve(token);
          window01.close();
        } catch (ex) {
          console.log("ex", ex);
          reject(null);
        }
      });
    });
  };
```

I tried to capture url token on load event, but for that I need to close pop up window and reopen it.

I want to basically capture/detect the redirect from facebook to my domain inside the pop up window.

Comment: _"I want to basically capture/detect the redirect from facebook to my domain inside the pop up window."_ - so why don't you write the code for that directly into the document your redirectUri returns then?

Comment: FYI: code and token are two different things.

Comment: @CBroe Hi thanks for your response. Do you mean to add code in parent window?

Comment: The redirectUri gets loaded in the window where you started the authorization flow, so in this case that will be the popup.

Comment: My issue is when the user has to retype or type for first time, their email and password. In that case FB directs back to my domain(inside pop up/child window), but in the parent window load event of child is not being fired, for which I am waiting to execute some code (for parsing of token and authenticating the user from my server to FB server and closing child window).  And child window is just stuck there. However if I manually close the child and reopen (click on continue with FB) child, it will directly go to my domain , due to cookies, and then my code in parent is executed properly.

Comment: _"but in the parent window load event of child is not being fired"_ - I am not sure if you can attach a load event handler like that and expect it to fire, when the popup "switches" to another domain and back. So try and handle this from inside the document loaded into the popup, the one that your redirectUri returns.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work somewhat now. I have handled this in parent Window but now i'm not able to send the child Window state to parent , as parent is stuck in the past state. My application is a SPA, and I have to manually reload the screen for state to be updated in parent. Any idea how to deal with this? Also really appreciate your support and your time. Thank you